# Stored procedure insert issues - multiple inserts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can you help me with this stored procedure? My problem is: when I create an account, my stored procedure works perfectly, but when I create a second account  in the table `evidenta_stundenti_materii`, my previous id of account gets doubled.

How many times does it insert when I create an account :

- in `tbl_utilizatori` : once
- in `tbl_studenti`: once
- in `tbl_evidenta_stundenti`: the previous id and the current id are re-inserted when I create the 2nd account

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertAnewAccAndANewStudent]
    (@email varchar(30),
     @parola varchar(30),
     @nume varchar(30),
     @prenume varchar(30),
     @adresa varchar(30),
     @nrTelefon varchar(30),
     @conectat bit,
     @idRol int,
     @idSpecializare varchar(30))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_utilizatori (email, parola, nume, prenume, adresa, nr_telefon, conectat, id_rol) 
    VALUES (@email, @parola, @nume, @prenume, @adresa, @nrTelefon, @conectat, @idRol)

    IF (@idRol = '1')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @id_utilizator int = @@identity

        INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_studenti  
        VALUES (@id_utilizator, @idSpecializare, '0', '1')
    END

    INSERT INTO dbo.[tbl.evidenta_stundeti_materii] (id_utilizator, id_materie, id_specializare)
        SELECT a.id_utilizator, b.id_materie, a.id_specializare
        FROM dbo.tbl_studenti a
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_materii b ON a.id_specializare=b.id_specializare
        WHERE a.id_specializare = @idSpecializare
END
```

Bad English, can provide ss for a better understand problem

Comment: The `tbl.evidenta_stundeti_materii` source select  statement is copying all rows with the `@idSpecializare` parameter value. You probably want to specify criteria with `@id_utilizator` to filter the newly inserted data.

Comment: I forgot to set the id
Thank youu

Comment: Side note, don't alias your tables with things like `a`, `b`, `c`, or `t1`, `t2`, `t3`. it ends up making your code harder to understand. Use appropriate aliases. `tbl_studenti` doesn't have a single `a` in it, and although `tbl_materii` has a `b` in it, the identifying part (`materii`) doesn't, so why alias them `a` and `b` respectively?  `s` and `m` would be much better alias options here. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Is there some reason to mix data types, e.g. `@idRol = '1'` to compare an `int` to a string?